# Why are the covariant and contravariant components of the metric tensor defined this way?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, tensor-products, tensor-rank

The metric tensor, using covariant components is $g_{ik}$ = $e^{(j)} \cdot e^{(k)}$ and using contravariant components it's $g^{ik}$ = $e_{(j)} \cdot e_{(k)}$. This seems counterintuitive to me. Why are the covariant components defined by the inner product of contravariant representations and vice versa? The text I'm reading doesn't go into a derivation and only says this occurs due to "[...] the transformation properties of the basis vectors when viewed from the standpoint of differential geometry." Can someone explain why the notation is like this?

Comment: This looks wrong to me (or at least a non-standard choice of notation). $g_{ik}$ is the inner product of the $j$th and $k$th basis vectors (not covectors). General vectors $v = \sum a^je_j$ and $w=\sum b^ke_k$ will have inner product $\langle v,w\rangle = \sum g_{jk}a^jb^k$, and the summation convention works out just fine. (I've only worked in and around differential geometry for almost 45 years ...)

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: Related question: let's say you have a contravariant vector representation: $v = a^{i} e_{i}$, why does the component have the raised index and the base vector a lowered one (vice versa for covariant, right)? Is this strictly convention?

Comment: The Einstein summation convention is that when you see an upper index $i$ and a lower index $i$, then the summation over $i$ is intended. So it's useful in this regard; personally, I always still write the summation symbol. But you also know that what you've written down is in fact a well-defined object (this is the whole point of tensors), independent of basis, because the transformation law of the $a^i$ will be the inverse of the transformation law of the $e_i$ when you change basis.